# Deleted /etc/modules - what can i do if it was deleted by mistake?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, xubuntu

I accidentally (and stupidly) overwritten my /etc/modules file.
I have no idea what was in it.

1. Is there a possibility to know what was in the file? like a backup file?
2. My system seems to works correctly? what might be the side effects deleting this file?
3. Will my NVIDIA drivers continue to work?

I am using Xubuntu 20.04 on Dell Laptop Latitude 5421

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is what my file looks like:[image].
There is some information, that is all. As long as you deleted the file and not the map etc/modules-load.d, then there is nothing to worry about. Just make a new one (now you know what the contents is).
If this helps you, please accept the answer.

Comment: Thank you. The question is what if it had relevant modules that I needed?

Comment: That question is irrelevant, because the file doesn't have the modules. The question should be 'what happens if I delete some relevant modules from my system?' Open another question and ask it.

Comment: It is relevant. I have deleted the /etc/modules file only and not the modules themselves. Is there a way to restore it?

Comment: Like written before, just make a new one now you know what the content is.